# Can we change origin after creation of bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to change the bucket origin to  **Mumbai** after creating the bucket origin to **Ohio**? as I am using edge cache for America.

Comment: What do you mean by bucket origin? Do you mean the AWS region in which the bucket was originally created?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are created in specific AWS regions.

Once the bucket is created, all data stored in the bucket remains in that location.

**If you wish to change the region of a bucket**, you will need to:

- Delete the bucket
- Wait a while for the name to become available again
- Create the bucket in the new region

Of course, you'll want to move the contents of the bucket somewhere so you don't lose it when  you delete the bucket.

An easier option is to simply create a new bucket with a different name, copy the data across, then delete the original bucket.